# Where does Magento store qty returned to stock for credit memos?

Tags: inventory, creditmemo

When creating a credit memo in Magento one has the option to return stock managed products to stock.

How can one tell - by looking at an existing credit memo - whether or not the admin decided to return any units to stock?

I've looked at the backend & the table structure and this information is seemingly not visible anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information about the return to stock is not kept in the database.
When a credit memo is created the method `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::refundOrderInventory()` is called.
In there an array is built with the qtys that need to return to stock based on the fact that the creditmemo item was previously marked with `setBackToStock(true)` or if the config setting for returning refunded products to stock is set to `Yes`.

Then the method `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::revertProductsSale()` is called with a parameter consisting of the array built from the item qtys.  This method is just a wrapper for `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_resource_Stock::correctItemsQty()` that actually runs the queries and updates the product stock.

But there is no code (or table field) that remembers if the qty was returned to stock or not.

Comment: 100% - Weird that the team @ Magento decided it wasn't notable to record this.

Comment: @moose. Yes and no. I kind of understand their reason not to remember this. First of all, code was needed for this, second, I'm not sure that this is really important. Well it seams to be in your case, but I never needed this.

Comment: The reasoning its important for me is for tracking stock movement. Say now a customer returns a product, you create a credit note for them, you want to sell that product again and as such want it returned to inventory. Now how do you know whether the admin actually DID return it to inventory?

Comment: @Marius - +1 for the answer , do you know in magento 2 which method call it for the same return to stock with credit memo ?